# Putting text next to an equation without moving the equation to the side

Tags: equations

I want to write something like:

```
\begin{equation}
f(x)=y \quad \text{(This is the equation lala)}
\end{equation}
```

But this essentially moves the equation out of the center.
I don't want the equation not being centered anymore. I rather want the text on the right of the centered equation. Is there an easy solution (like naming an equation and letting that appear somehow...)?

Comment: `\begin{equation}
f(x)=y \rlap{\quad\text{(This is the equation lala)}}
\end{equation}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want to **align** something?

```
\begin{align}
f(x)&=y &&\text{tralala}
\end{align}
```

if you want to stick with equation you could simply tell latex to ignore the width of the text

```
\begin{equation}
f(x)=y \rlap{\quad \text{tralala}}
\end{equation}
```